# How do negative powers and fractional powers make sense?

Tags: exponentiation

We know that powers are the number of times a number is multiplied with itself. Like $2^3$ means $(2×2×2)$, $5^4$ means $(5×5×5×5)$, etc. But how do negative powers make sense? What does it mean to multiply a number *negative number of times* by itself? And how are they the reciprocal of their positive counterparts?

Same question for fractional powers, how come they end up as roots?

Comment: For every real $n$ , we have $a^{-n}=\frac{1}{a^n}$ if $a>0$. This follows from the deifinition of $a^0=1$ and the power rule $a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$ giving $a^{-n}\cdot a^n=a^0=1$

Comment: $2^{-3}=(2^3)^{-1}$ is the number who when multiplied by $2^3$ will result in $(2^3)^{-1}\times 2^3 = 1$.  You can think of it as $2^{-3} = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: $a^{1/n}$ is the same as the $n$-th root of $a$ because of $(a^{1/n})^n=a^{1/n\cdot n}=a^1=a$

Comment: "*What does it mean to multiply a number negative number of times by itself*"  The correlation between exponentiation and "multiplying a number by itself" only really works as an analogy for case of natural numbers as exponents.  You should discard that analogy and grow to use the *actual* definition when moving on to other cases.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4187522/21813) is another explanation.